# Loading custom fixtures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

We are trying to load fixtures for a group of models that uses a different database connection than ActiveRecord::Base (inheriting from Foo::Base in this example).

We've created this module that we include in ActiveSupport::TestCase and the specify a path to the .yml files and e.g. `foo_fitures :all`. This works great for the first test that runs. Fixture accessors are defined and records are found in the database. But for subsequent tests there are no records in the database.

```
module Foo::Fixtures
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    setup :setup_foo_fixtures
    teardown :teardown_foo_fixtures

    class_attribute :foo_fixture_path
    class_attribute :foo_fixture_table_names

    self.foo_fixture_table_names = []
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo_fixtures(*fixture_names)
      if fixture_names.first == :all
        fixture_names = Dir[foo_fixture_path.join("**/*.yml")].map { |f| File.basename(f, ".yml") }
      else
        fixture_names = fixture_names.flatten.map { |n| n.to_s }
      end

      self.foo_fixture_table_names |= fixture_names
      require_fixture_classes(fixture_names)
      setup_fixture_accessors(fixture_names)
    end
  end

  def setup_foo_fixtures
    @loaded_fixtures.merge!(load_foo_fixtures)
  end

  def teardown_foo_fixtures
    Foo::Base.clear_active_connections!
  end

  private

  def load_foo_fixtures
    foo_classes = Foo::Base.subclasses.flat_map { |klass| klass.abstract_class ? klass.subclasses : klass }
    class_names = foo_classes.each_with_object({}) do |klass, memo|
      memo[klass.table_name.to_sym] = klass if klass.table_name.present? && foo_fixture_table_names.include?(klass.table_name)
    end
    foo_fixtures = ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures(foo_fixture_path, foo_fixture_table_names, class_names) do
      Foo::Base.connection
    end
    Hash[foo_fixtures.map { |f| [f.name, f] }]
  end
end
```

Rails' fixture system is a bit convoluted, and I'm not able to figure out what we are missing to make sure that our extra fixtures are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It looks like it might be the transactions that are removing our fixtures from the database. My guess is that the transaction has started before our code loads in the fixtures, so that's why they are there for the first test, but gone at the second.

So we changed strategy, and now we just hook into `load_fixtures` and `fixtures`. This works just fine.

```
module FooFixtures
  module ClassMethods
    def foo_fixture_classes
      collect_subclasses = ->(k) { k.abstract_class ? k.subclasses.flat_map(&collect_subclasses) : k }
      Foo::Base.subclasses.flat_map(&collect_subclasses)
    end

    def foo_fixture_path
      Rails.root.join("test/foo_fixtures")
    end

    def foo_fixture_table_names
      Dir[foo_fixture_path.join("**/*.yml")].map { |f| File.basename(f, ".yml") }
    end

    def fixtures(*fixture_names)
      super
      if fixture_names.first == :all
        require_fixture_classes(foo_fixture_table_names)
        setup_fixture_accessors(foo_fixture_table_names)
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def load_fixtures
    foo_fixture_path = self.class.foo_fixture_path
    foo_fixture_table_names = self.class.foo_fixture_table_names
    class_names = self.class.foo_fixture_classes.each_with_object({}) do |klass, memo|
      memo[klass.table_name.to_sym] = klass if klass.table_name.present? && foo_fixture_table_names.include?(klass.table_name)
    end
    foo_fixtures = ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures(foo_fixture_path, foo_fixture_table_names, class_names) do
      Foo::Base.connection
    end

    super.merge(Hash[foo_fixtures.map { |f| [f.name, f] }])
  end
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  extend FooFixtures::ClassMethods
  prepend FooFixtures

  self.foo_fixture_classes.each do |fixture_class|
    set_fixture_class fixture_class.table_name.to_sym => fixture_class
  end

  ...
end
```